# How to wait for line of code to finish before moving onto the next line

Tags: vb.net, buttonclick

I'm using Visual Basic 2010, and within my form shown sub I need two buttons to be pressed , however I need the first button's code to complete before the moving on to pressing the next button. Is there any way to allow this to happen? Thanks :)

```
  Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

    BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.PerformClick()))

   'I need this next button click to be carried out after the one above has completely finished

    BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.PerformClick()))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use methods instead of "button-clicks":

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    MoveLastItem()
    MovePreviousItem()
End Sub

Private Sub MoveLastItem()
    bindingSource1.MoveLast();
End Sub

Private Sub MovePreviousItem()
    bindingSource1.MovePrevious();
End Sub
```

You just have call these methods from the button-click events handlers as well.

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem_Clicked(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Click
    MoveLastItem()
End Sub

Private Sub BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem_Clicked(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Click
    MovePreviousItem()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What would I have to put in the two subs where you've put 'implement logic here ? Apologies I'm still very new to code

Comment: @AaronH: The same code that you now have in your button-click event handlers. Just move it from there into the methods, then your code is also more reusable and readable. You can call the methods from wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you I shall give that a go.

Comment: The problem I am having is that because the BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem and BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem buttons are no longer being clicked, the bindingnavigator isn't moving positions.

Comment: @AaronH: If you use a `BindingSource` you can use it's [`MoveLast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.movelast.aspx) and [`MovePrevious`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.moveprevious.aspx) methods instead (edited my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I don't do VB, but I came across this page and it might be useful to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

If that is not relevant, in your situation I would either use the buttons to set flags and simply if-test the flags, or create a do-while loop so that the code can finish executing while the conditions are met. Careful with those, however, as infinite loops are something they are good at.

Another thought is to enable the second button in the last line of the code of the first button?

Hope something helps. Apologies if it is of no use.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) problem has now been solved though.